# Custom Logging within sql server 2008 Scheduler Job > View Histroy?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I am creating sql server 2008 Agent scheduler job form sql script.
Want to Log the details if failed in some case within Job > View Histroy.

Is there any way, so we can log custom text with Job > View Histroy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the print command in your SQL script

i.e.

```
Print "Script Started"

-- Do something interesting

Print "Script Finished"
```

Then look at the individual step to see the output. The only problem is that it will look something like this:

```
Message
Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.  Script Started [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  Script Finished [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0).  The step succeeded.
```

Which is a bit awkward to extract.